# How to extract a word after specific character in batch program?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For example I have a text file `test.txt` that contains like this:

> ```
> Item1 $23 Item2 $24
> Item3 $25
> ```

When I run this script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=$ tokens=1*" %%A in (test.txt) do echo %%B >> result.txt
```

The result is:

> ```
> 23 Item2 $24
> 25
> ```

I want the result is:

> ```
> 23
> 24
> 25
> ```

How should I repair the script?

Comment: Simple with [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044): `jrepl "\$(\d+)" "$txt=$1" /jmatchq /f "test.txt" /o "result.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script (see the explanatory `rem` remarks in the code):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_IFILE=test.txt"
set "_OFILE=result.txt"

rem // Store line-break in variable:
(set ^"LF=^
%= blank line =%
^")

rem // Write to resulting file:
> "%_OFILE%" (
    rem // Loop through lines of text file:
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%_IFILE%") do (
        rem // Store current line in variable:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to be able to write and read variable in same code block:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Replace each `$` by line-break and loop over resulting lines skipping the first one:
        for /F "skip=1" %%K in (^"!LINE:$^=^%LF%%LF%!^") do (
            rem // Return first token of each line:
            echo(%%K
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

At first, this replaces every `$` by a line-break, so the first line of `test.txt` becomes:

> ```cmd
> Item1 
> 23 Item2 
> 24
> ```

And the second one becomes:

> ```cmd
> Item3
> 25
> ```

Then it extracts the first <kbd>SPACE</kbd>- or <kbd>TAB</kbd>-separated token from each of the newly formed multi-line strings, skipping the first line, so only the numbers are returned.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but after I run the result is empty..

Comment: @mkdarhdm Now it works, there was a caret missing in front of the equal sign `!LINE:$^=^%LF%%LF%!`

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%A in (test.txt) do (
 for %%T in (%%A) do (
  set "term=%%T"
  if "!term:~0,1!"=="$" echo !term:~1!
 )
)>> result.txt
endlocal
```

Read each line to `%%A`. Tokenise to `%%T`. Assign each token in turn to `term`, examine the first character and if `$`, `echo` the term, except the first character.

Comment: @compo: I've got to stop doing this until I've had my coffee. Completely misread the Q.

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%i in ("test.txt") do (
    set "_br=%%i"
    echo(!_br: =^

!
  )
)>_tmp
(for /f "delims=$ tokens=*" %%a in ('type _tmp ^| find "$"') do echo %%a)>result.txt
```

**Note** that you must copy the script as is. The extract of the script as show below does the replacement of whitespace with new line and therefore cannot change at all, the position and the extra line must remain as is for this to work as intended.

```
    echo(!_br: =^

!
```

This script just splits each word separated by a space and redirects it to a new file, we then specifically search for the words containing `$` and redirect those hits only.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, the script run perfectly ..

Comment: I'm sorry, but apparently the script didn't work if the number of words was large or the number of lines was too much..

Comment: Well then you would need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to post this example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to show a method of parsing each line and returning every other string, *(doesn't work with poison characters)*.

```bat
@(For /F "UseBackQDelims=" %%A In ("test.txt")Do @(Set "i=0"
    For %%B In (%%A)Do @(Set /A "i=(i+1)%%2"&Cmd /V:On /Q /C Exit !i!
        If Not ErrorLevel 1 Echo %%B)))>"results.txt"
```

In your posted example code and 'wanted' result, you could probably use that idea to output the strings with their first character removed if it is a <kbd>$</kbd>.

```bat
@(For /F "UseBackQDelims=" %%A In ("test.txt")Do @(Set "i=0"
    For %%B In (%%A)Do @(Set /A "i=(i+1)%%2"&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If !i! Equ 0 (Set "Val=%%B"&If "!Val:~,1!"=="$" (Echo !Val:~1!
            )Else Echo %%B)&EndLocal)))>"results.txt"
```